# What is wrong with my Regex conversion from php to javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, regex

I seem to be having problems converting some php Regex code into Javascript Regex code.  The php version works flawlessly, and it was one of our fellow users, jim tollan, that wrote the php code that inspired me to write it in javascript because I need it done on the client-side.  The code pulls out content between html tags based on the specified tag attribute (id, class, etc..) and the value of that attribute.

Here is the original code by **jim tollan**:

```
<?php
function get_tag( $attr, $value, $xml ) {

    $attr = preg_quote($attr);
    $value = preg_quote($value);

    $tag_regex = '/<div[^>]*'.$attr.'="'.$value.'">(.*?)<\\/div>/si';

    preg_match($tag_regex,
    $xml,
    $matches);
    return $matches[1];
}

$yourentirehtml = file_get_contents("test.html");
$extract = get_tag('id', 'content', $yourentirehtml);
echo $extract; 
?>
```

And here is the javascript code I've written and embedded in html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function get_tag(attr, value, xml) {

  var attr = preg_quote(attr);
  var value = preg_quote(value);

  var tag_regex = new RegExp('/<input[^>]*'+attr+'="'+value+'">(.*?)<\\/label>/si');

  // preg_match
  xml.match(tag_regex);
}

var yourentirehtml = file_get_contents("test.html");
var extract = get_tag('id', 'custom-63', yourentirehtml);
alert(extract);
</script>
```

*I used the functions defined at phpjs.org to define both **preg_quote** and **file_get_contents***

Here is the test.html file that I'm using:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div id="content">
<!--content-->

<p>some content</p>

<!--content-->
</div>

<label>
<input type="radio" name="testingMethod" id="custom-63">
"  Radio Button Text  "
</label>

</body>
</html>
```

When I run the php file, it works, but when I run the javascript code, the alert box shows

> undefined

I want to know if my implementation of the expression in **var tag_regex** is correct, and if it is, is there anything in my code that is preventing me from the yielding the results I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by scrapping the idea of using regex, and I decided to go with using the DOM.  It can be done rather simply by doing this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var x=document.getElementsByTagName("label")[];
// put the index of the element within the square brackets if you have more than one with the same name
// 0 is the first index
// you can also use getElementsById or getElementsByTagName

var result = x.innerText;
// you can also do x.cell[].innerText if you have more than one item within the element you found above
// 0 is the first index, and any index number should be put within the square brackets
</script>
```